# React Native "keyboardDismissMode" at FlatList

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

Is there any possibility to prevent the keyboard from dismissing when scrolling a **FlatList**?

When using a ScrollView setting the prop "keyboardDismissMode" to "none" is the solution to this problem, but this doesn't work for me at a FlatList...

I use the FlatList inside a self-made component, that is in a Stack-Navigator, while there is a focussed TextInput in its header. I render the FlatList like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <FlatList 
    style={{flex: 1}}
    data={this.props.data}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
  />
</View>
```

The renderItem() function:

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <TouchableHighlight
    style={{paddingVertical: 10}}
    onPress={() => {
      this.props.onChooseItem(item);
    }}
  >
    <Text numberOfLines={1} >
      {item.text}
    </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for how you're rendering the FlatList component in question?

Comment: Do my changes in the question help? I have added how and where I render the FlatList.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might think about to encapsulate your FlatList in a ScrollView?

Even if this **seems to solve the issue**, it's **NOT a recommended way!**

That's because if it force rerendering the whole flatlist, each time you scroll the screen.

You might better try a component like [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

I've found this article with some alternate Ideas to fix it:
[How to use KeyboardAvoidingView with FlatList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930413/how-to-use-keyboardavoidingview-with-flatlist)

Check: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboarddismissmode

Comment: It was a bad way for that: https://forums.expo.io/t/warning-virtualizedlists-should-never-be-nested-inside-plain-scrollviews-with-the-same-orientation-use-another-virtualizedlist-backed-container-instead/31361/9

Comment: FlatList inside a ScrollView is a bad idea. Just rendering the required component without the FlatList will give the same result.

Comment: Since FlatList inherits ScrollView props, can't he just avoid this encapsulation and use the desired prop directly from the flatlist?  See the link in my answer.  I tried it with the `onScrollBeginDrag` property and it works

Answer (score 1):

The docs [at the beginning of the reference section](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) says that FlatList "Inherits ScrollView Props, unless it is nested in another FlatList of same orientation."
So I think you can just do use that keyboardDismissMode without encapsulation in a scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

No need of scrollview inside flatlist it will create performance issue.

just add `onScrollBeginDrag={Keyboard.dismiss}` in flatlist. it will work in android as well iOS while     `keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'` will work only in iOS