# React Native | How access to endCoordinates of Keyboard using Typescript and recompose

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, higher-order-components, recompose

So I use recompoose and typescript in my react native app, and I trying to access to endCoordinates for Keyboard the get the Keyboard height. I followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html) article and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587006/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-keyboard-in-react-native) but I am not able to access to endCoordinates, it's always undefined.

This is what I tried :

```
const withLifeCycle = lifecycle<Handlers, {}> ({
     componentDidMount() {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.props._keyboardDidShow)
},
 componentWillUnmount() {
   // @ts-ignore
   this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
 }
})    


interface Handlers {
  _keyboardDidShow: (e:any) => void;
}
// WrappedProps have some other props for some other part of codes

export const enhance = compose<WrappedProps, Props>(
withHandlers<
Props,
{}
>({
  _keyboardDidShow: (e) => () =>{
     console.log(e.endCoordinates) // This is Undefined
   }
 }),
 withLifeCycle
);
```

I think the problem is the way I need to pass the keyboardDidShow event type to the method, because `e` object does not have any `endCoordinates`.

Answer (score 0):

import `KeyboardEvent` from `react-native`

`const _keyboardDidShow = (props: KeyboardEvent)`

`const { endCoordinates } = props;`